# Firebase+GTM SDK - tracking exceptions and crashes in Google Analytics

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Google Analytics allows collection of a basic contextual information and crash and exception in app. This has been done using GA library. I am currently upgrading the implementation to use Google Tag Manager by utilising latest version Firebase+Tag Manager SDK.

I wonder how can I make sure crashes from my app are registered within GA? Firebase crashlitycs is a different tool. I really need those crashes and exceptions in Google Analytics as exceptions/crashes rather than just events.

Please advice. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a tag in GTM (exception type) and use the event 'app_exception' (in firebase) as a trigger, sending that information to GA.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I can 
Unfortunately there is no _exception_ trigger in neither Legacy container type nor latest (firebase) therefore do I need to intercept exceptions myself and deliver to SDK?

Also is 'app_exception' event thrown automatically?

Comment: I linked crashlytics to firebase, in order to see those events: app_exception. Guess they were not available before that.